# .NET application crash on PlayOnLinux (WINE)

Tags: .net, ubuntu, wine

I've created a Win32 prefix and inside of it put .NET 4.0. Then I've installed the application. When I run it (through playonline --run "app" 'parameter') everything seems fine, put as I try to navigare inside of it, I get this error

> "Could not load file or assembly "System.Data, version=4.0.0.0", Culture=neutral, >publickeytoken=[...]", or one of its dependencies. Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002

I found another question which is solved by adding in app.conf this tag:

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" />
</startup>
```

But with me it didn't work.